# Splitting a string, duplicating each character and re-joining to form new string Abcd would become AAbbccdd

Tags: javascript, string

I need to be able to duplicate the characters of a string and recombine using my function so Abcd would become AAbbccdd etc..

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
  let output = str.split("");
  let result = "";
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result = output[i] + output[i]
  }
  return (result)
}
console.log(doubleChar("Abcd"));
```

Comment: Change `result =` to `result +=`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is is a completely different approach but that is how I (shorthand fanboy) would do it:

```js
const doubleChar = (str) => str.split("").reduce((a, b) => a + b + b, "");

console.log(doubleChar("Abcd"));
```

If you want to stick to your version. This is how you could make it work:

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
  let output = str.split("");
  let result = "";
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += output[i] + output[i]; // <- change = to +=
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(doubleChar("Abcd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing `result` every time. Change the `result =` to `result +=` so you append to it instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark I see it now that's great mate as I had the right solution all be it like you pointed out I was replacing result everytime in the loop rather than adding to it. Have a great evening

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
result = output[i] + output[i]
```

with

```
result = result + output[i] + output[i]
```

Comment: Note: just `result += ...` would do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array of characters and use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to duplicate the items, then join back together:

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
  return str.split("").flatMap(i => [i,i]).join('') 
}
console.log(doubleChar("Abcd"));
```

Comment: Thank you that looks great 

Comment: @JonathanJoseph No problem. If it solves your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to do it is to map each character and return it x2:

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
 return str.split("").map(c => c+c).join("");
}
console.log(doubleChar("Abcd"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Good question Jonathan. I would recommend looking into some string functions as well as some array functions.

Here are a few to get started ->

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

An approach with these functions could be as simple as

```
function doubleChar(str) {               // "abc"
  return str.split('')                   // ["a","b","c"]
            .map(char => char.repeat(2)) // ["aa","bb","cc"]
            .join('');                   // "aabbcc"
}
```

To simplify your approach, you can iterate over the string character-by-character by using a `for of` loop

```
function doubleChar(str) {
  let doubledStr = '';
  for (let character of str) {
    doubledStr += character.repeat(2);
  }
  return doubledStr;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you that will be a useful read. I am preparing for an entry test to a 3 month Javascript bootcamp so I need to learn as much as I can to get ready